# R: Performing functions on a grouped data frame based on conditions

Tags: r

I have the following tibble in R:

| ID | Date | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/12/2002 | 0 |
| A | 15/12/2002 | 0 |
| B | 15/12/2002 | 0 |
| B | 16/12/2002 | 0 |
| B | 17/12/2002 | 1 |
| B | 18/12/2002 | 1 |
| C | 15/12/2002 | 1 |
| C | 18/12/2002. | 1 |

I want to generate a table based on the following conditions:for IDs which are duplicates:
If all test results are equal to 0, keep only the latest test result.
If there are test results equal to 0 and 1, keep the earliest test result that equals 1.
If all test results are equal to 1, keep only the earliest test result.

The result would look like:

| ID | Date | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15/12/2002 | 0 |
| B | 17/12/2002 | 1 |
| C | 15/12/2002 | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried already, where are you stuck?

Comment: I think an approach could be to use group_modify from dplyr based on the conditionals listed.

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- read.delim(text = '
ID  Date    Test
A   12/12/2002  0
A   15/12/2002  0
B   15/12/2002  0
B   16/12/2002  0
B   17/12/2002  1
B   18/12/2002  1
C   15/12/2002  1
C   18/12/2002  1
')

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = '%d/%m/%y')

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  group_modify(~ {
    if (all(.x$Test == 0)) 
      slice_tail(.x)
    else if (any(.x$Test == 1))
      slice_max(.x, Test, with_ties = FALSE)
  })
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID    Date        Test
#>   <chr> <date>     <int>
#> 1 A     2020-12-15     0
#> 2 B     2020-12-17     1
#> 3 C     2020-12-15     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>